# Isometric tile has jagged lines

Tags: directx, directx-11

So i am trying to render a small isometric tile-map and just started with a single tile to feel the thing out. But i am running into a problem where if the tile gets "too small" (actually 64x64 which is the exact same size as the texture is) it gets jagged lines, even though it looks ok on the texture itself. The strange thing is that it also appears to be right if i use the Graphics Debugger in Visual Studio. Here is a picture to better visualize what i mean:

[image]

The left picture is a part of the rendered frame inside a normal window. The right part is the captured frame for the graphics debugging tool. As you can see the display for the captured frame looks completely ok. The normal rendering inside a window also starts to look good if i scale this tile up by some factor. Any ideas why this might happen? Here is the original texture if it is to any help.

[image]

One further note: I create the "texture" by rendering an object in blender while setting up the camera like this: http://flarerpg.org/tutorials/isometric_tiles/ (As my understanding this should be one good way for rendering it in DirectX)

**EDIT:** Here is my Sampler Desc. I am creating the texture by using the `CreateDDSTextureFromFile` method provided by the DirectXTK (https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK).

```
CreateDDSTextureFromFile(gfx->GetGraphicsDevice()->GetDevice(), L"resources/house_tile.DDS", nullptr, shaderResource.GetAddressOf())

g_defaultSamplerDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_LINEAR_MAG_POINT_MIP_LINEAR;
g_defaultSamplerDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
g_defaultSamplerDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
g_defaultSamplerDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
g_defaultSamplerDesc.MipLODBias = 0.0f;
g_defaultSamplerDesc.MaxAnisotropy = 1;
g_defaultSamplerDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
g_defaultSamplerDesc.BorderColor[0] = 0;
g_defaultSamplerDesc.BorderColor[1] = 0;
g_defaultSamplerDesc.BorderColor[2] = 0;
g_defaultSamplerDesc.BorderColor[3] = 0;
g_defaultSamplerDesc.MinLOD = 0;
g_defaultSamplerDesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;
```

**EDIT 2:** I checked the .dds file and there is only 1 Mip-Level. Here is also the Texture description which the DirectXTK method is using. Seems fine to me:

```
        Width   64  unsigned int
        Height  64  unsigned int
        MipLevels   1   unsigned int
        ArraySize   1   unsigned int
        Format  DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM (87) DXGI_FORMAT
+       SampleDesc  {Count=1 Quality=0 }    DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC
        Usage   D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT (0) D3D11_USAGE
        BindFlags   8   unsigned int
        CPUAccessFlags  0   unsigned int
        MiscFlags   0   unsigned int
```

And for what it's worth here is also my Vertex-Setup:

```
Vertex v[] =
{
    Vertex(-32.f, -32.f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex(-32.f, 32.f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
    Vertex(32.0f, -32.f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex(32.0f, 32.f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
};
```

Which should create the quad at a size of 64x64.

**EDIT 3:** I tried to generate Mip-Maps to see if that works, but it did not. Here are two Mip-Levels of the 7 available:

[image: Mip-Level 1 and 2]

And also the new Texture description:

```
        Width   64  unsigned int
        Height  64  unsigned int
        MipLevels   7   unsigned int
        ArraySize   1   unsigned int
        Format  DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM (87) DXGI_FORMAT
+       SampleDesc  {Count=1 Quality=0 }    DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC
        Usage   D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT (0) D3D11_USAGE
        BindFlags   8   unsigned int
        CPUAccessFlags  0   unsigned int
        MiscFlags   0   unsigned int
```

Looks fine to me, but the result is still the same :/.

Comment: Do you use mipmapping and no point filtering? It looks like a sampling issue to me.

Comment: I am not using Mip-Mapping. Can not check to be sure, but i will as soon as i am home. Thanks!

Comment: @Gnietschow I added my sampler description and how i create the shader resource view. Do you see anything wrong there?

Comment: For me the sampler looks good. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the DirectXTK, does it generate mipmaps for your texture on load? If not, does you dds contains the mipmaps?

Comment: @Gnietschow : It can create mipmaps if so desired, but it wasn't for me. I checked my .dds file and it only contains 1 Mip-Level. I also checked the texture description for the texture the DirectXTK is creating and using for the ShaderResourceView. See above.

Comment: Than you should try to create mipmaps for your texture and I'm sure your jagged lines will disappear. If you're scaling your tile smaller, the sampler can only use the original texture, which has more texels than the result, leading to skip some of them at the sampling => no straight lines at some smaller scales due to undersampling.

Comment: @Gnietschow Sadly that also did not work. Any other suggestions? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I'm starting to run dry of ideas. The only difference to my own setups, is that i used linear filtering even for magnification `g_defaultSamplerDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;`. I tried your texture and on each zoom level it gets a little blurry due to filtering, but never jagged.

Comment: @Gnietschow yeah sadly that also did not help. I am really confused..there is one thing i noticed: When i zoom a little bit in or out of the frame (with Nvidia Nsight for example) the edge gets straight..

Comment: You need to offset the vertex ( or the texcoord ) by half a pixel most probably, this is because the pixel center is at 0.5 with direct x ( different from GL ). If you don't you read in fact in between two texels, and then the hardware may pick either ( in point mode ) based on precision issues. That is say, if you quad is made at the dimension of the texture and you seek a one to one draw of course.

Comment: Not sure if this is still an issue with Dx11: http://www.asawicki.info/news_1516_half-pixel_offset_in_directx_11.html . i will still Test tomorrow nevertheless. Thanks!

Comment: @puelo it is true for sv_position, but if you generate position and texcoords your self, you still need to think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gnietschow: Thank you for your effort. The solution was quite simple and it was found by some people in the gamedev.net board:

**Quotes:**

> I had a similiar issue once, and it turned out I was doing windowed
>   mode wrong in terms of calculating the window size to fit the
>   backbuffer size etc., resulting in a vaguely stretched display that
>   was hard to notice for a long while

---

> I was going to say the same thing. You want to make sure that the
>   client area of your window is the same size as your D3D backbuffer,
>   otherwise you'll get really crappy scaling when the backbuffer is blit
>   onto the window. You can use something like this:
>
> ```
> RECT windowRect;
> SetRect(&windowRect, 0, 0, backBufferWidth, backBufferHeight);
>
> BOOL isMenu = (GetMenu(hwnd) != nullptr);
> if(AdjustWindowRectEx(&windowRect, style, isMenu, exStyle) == 0)
>     DoErrorHandling();
>
> if(SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, windowRect.right - windowRect.left, windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top, SWP_NOMOVE) == 0)
>     DoErrorHandling();
> ```

Source: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/677243-iso-dimetric-tile-texture-has-jagged-edges/